# what's the smallest proper answer to http requests for favicon.ico

Tags: http, webserver, favicon

I am working on a very simple web server.

Till now I haven't found how to disable the annoying requests for favicon.ico from chrome.

So I was thinking what's the shortest/fastest answer to such a request. Is it ok just to disconnect after the request for favicon.ico is identified. Or is that considered impolite behaviour and should be avoided?

Alternativly I would send a 404 message. Do I need to send a text as well or do I have to send at least the information "content-length: 0" or can I even leave this?

Thank you!

Comment: Notice that a fully HTTP compliant server cannot be simple (because the details of HTTP specifications are complex). I don't understand why you would want to handle `favicon.ico` specifically: most web servers handle it as any other URL (e.g. 404).

Comment: An HTTP server might not necessarily need to be fully compliant in order to be usable for specific tasks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6), the shortest valid response would be

```
HTTP/1.0 404 <CRLF>
<CRLF>
```

There should be a space between `404` and the line terminator, actually separating the status code from the status reason message (which is an empty string in this case). This might not be strictly required, but I doubt saving a single byte is worth the minor deviation from the RFC.